# Dudas con la POO

Tags: java

He creado dos clases, Autor y Libro.

```
public class Autor {

private final String nombreAutor;
private final String email;
private final char sexo;
private final  Libro[] libros;
private final Libro[] librosEscritos;


public Autor(String nombreAutor, String email, char sexo, Libro[] libros, Libro[] librosEscritos) {
    this.nombreAutor = nombreAutor;
    this.email = email;
    this.sexo = sexo;
    this.libros = libros;
    this.librosEscritos = librosEscritos;
}



//Metodos get y set
public String getNombre() {
    return nombreAutor;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public char getSexo() {
    return sexo;
}

public Libro[] getLibros() {
    return libros;
}

public Libro[] getLibrosEscritos() {
    return librosEscritos;
}

  public Libro[] setLibrosEscritos() {
    return librosEscritos;
}


public Libro[] setLibros() {
    return libros;
}

public String setNombre() {
    return nombreAutor;
}

public String setEmail() {
    return email;
}

public char setSexo() {
    return sexo;
}
```

public class Libro {

```
private final String nombreLibro;

private final double precio;
private final int cantidadEnStock;
private final Autor[] autores;
private final String librosEscritos;

public Libro(String nombreLibro, double precio, int cantidadEnStock, Autor[] autores, String librosEscritos) {
    this.nombreLibro = nombreLibro;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.cantidadEnStock = cantidadEnStock;
    this.autores = autores;
    this.librosEscritos=librosEscritos;
}

//Metodos get y set
public String getNombre() {
    return nombreLibro;
}

public double getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public int getCantidadEnStock() {
    return cantidadEnStock;
}

public Autor[] getAutores() {
    return autores;
}

public String getLibrosEscritos() {
    return librosEscritos;
}

   public String setLibrosEscritos() {
    return librosEscritos;
}

public Autor[] setAutores() {
    return autores;
}

public String setNombre() {
    return nombreLibro;
}

public double setPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public int setCantidadEnStock() {
    return cantidadEnStock;
}
```

Pero no entiendo como hacer "añade un atributo nuevo en la clase Autor que será “librosEscritos: Lista(Libro)”. ¿Estaría bien hecho como lo he puesto? No acabo de entender que hacer **“librosEscritos: Lista(Libro)”.**  Gracias

Comment: 'librosEscritos: Lista(Libro) simplemente te está diciendo que el atributo ha de llamarse 'librosEscritos' y que ha de ser de tipo Lista(Libro). El cambio que haría sobre lo tuyo es que has creado un vector de tipo 'Libro', yo crearía una lista de tipo 'Libro' que es lo que te piden. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: Entonces ¿habría que crear un método que devolviera algo de tipo lista libro, o simplemente poner los atributos en el constructor de cada clase? Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Sólo te pide añadir el tipo. Así que con añadirlo a la clase como has hecho y hacer su set y get si quieres ya vale. Lo único que yo lo crearía como una lista pues así te lo piden. private final List<Libro> librosEscritos;

Comment: @Quidi90 quizás deberías publicarlo como respuesta. Sería mucho más cómodo leer esos comentarios bien formateados y con más detalle (además, los comentarios son para aclarar, no para dar respuestas). De esa forma podríamos, por ejemplo, votar por tu solución.

Answer (score 0):

'librosEscritos: Lista(Libro) simplemente te está diciendo que el atributo ha de llamarse 'librosEscritos' y que ha de ser de tipo Lista(Libro). El cambio que haría sobre lo tuyo es que has creado un vector de tipo 'Libro', yo crearía una lista de tipo 'Libro' que es lo que te piden.

```
private final List<Libro> librosEscritos;
```

docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: Cambiaría lo que has llamado vector a arreglo. Si llamas vector a un arreglo tipo `Libro[]` puede confundirse con `Vector<Libro>` que tiene otras implicaciones y no está usando.